# How to Query expired case milestone?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-flow

I am trying to query all expired milestones so that I can use them in my flow. My requirement is to send a custom notification to the case owner once a milestone expires. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this query to get a case with expired milestones:

```
SELECT Id,Case.Case Number,Case.Account.Id,Case.Account.Name,Start Date,Target Date,Violated FROM Case Milestone WHERE Violated = true ORDER BY Creation Date DESC
```

I hope I have satisfied your question.